# Custom User Settings In A Plugin Template

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frontend, settings

I have no problem submitting the initial default user data, and no problems recalling data.  However, i can not figure out why this form is throwing an error (needed to submit user data).

Here is the code I'm using to create the default data...

```
// DEFAULT USER OPTIONS
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sci_pages_register_setting' );
function sci_pages_register_setting()
{
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$default_options=array(
'sci_avatar'=>'http://.../blank_avatar.png',
'sci_facebook'=>'',
'sci_twitter'=>''
);
add_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options',$default_options);
register_setting( $user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options', $user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options', 'sci_pages_sanitize' );
}
function sci_pages_sanitize( $in )
{
return $in; 
}
```

And this is the form code...  And I'm really not sure what it is that I need to do for this to...

A.  Stop throwing up an error
B.  Allow users to submit this information from the front-end page.

```
<?PHP
function sci_options_page()
{
?>
<div class="wrap">

<h1>User Options</h1>
<?PHP
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$options = get_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options');
settings_fields($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options');
?>
<form method="post" action="#"> 


<table class="form-table">
<tr valign="top">
<th><h2>General</h2><th>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="sci_avatar">Avatar:</label></th>
<td><input type="text" id="sci_logo" size="50" name="sci_options[sci_avatar]" value="<?php echo $options['sci_avatar']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th><h2>Social Links</h2><th>

</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="sci_facebook">Facebook:</label></th>
<td><input type="text" id="sci_vimeo" size="50" name="sci_options[sci_facebook]" value="<?php echo $options['sci_facebook']; ?>" /></td>

</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="sci_twitter">Twitter:</label></th>
<td><input type="text" id="sci_skype" size="50" name="sci_options[sci_twitter]" value="<?php echo $options['sci_twitter']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<?php 
submit_button(); 
?>
</form>
</div>
<?php
} 
sci_options_page();
?>
```

This is what I see in the front-end when accessing the page...

[image]

**What am I doing wrong (other than feeling like a complete noob right now)?**

Comment: Did you click on the "Learn more about debugging in WordPress" link yet? If so, what does your `debug.log` file says?

Comment: It didn't give me anything helpful.  Besides, i now have the submit button appearing and the error is gone... However, it still does not save the data when submitted.  Just comes back to the page with nothing new.